# Visio activex shapes vertices

Tags: c#, visio

i am using in my c# project visio activex to import visio floorplan drawings.
and i need to get the vertices of the shapes in that drawing, and i can't find any method or property for it.
if someone has any ideas please help.

Comment: This question should be on SuperUser.com as it's not programming related.

Comment: How is this not programming related?  They're asking for help with an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BoundingBox method on the shape class to retrieve the dimensions of the box around a shape.

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms195983%28v=office.12%29.aspx) page will give you more information about the method, it returns the top, bottom, left and right of the box, so it should be possible to work out the vertices from that.

Answer (score 0):

Visio uses a PinX and a PinY to describe the location of a shape using the shapes Height and Width will allow you to calculate the vertices.